# JUnit5 Testing JDBC function

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following JDBC function which updates the database to add a new user

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

 @Autowired
 PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
 @Autowired
 DataSource datasource;
 @Autowired
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

 public int register(User user) {

  String uniqueusername = "select * from users where username='" + user.getUsername() + "'";
  List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(uniqueusername, new UserMapper());
  if(users.size() == 0) {

String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());

String sql = "insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] { 
        user.getUsername(), 
        encryptedPassword,
        user.getFirstname(),
        user.getLastname(), 
        user.getEmail(), 
        user.getAddress() });
      }

else {
    return 0;
}
  }
```

I am trying to test this function using JUnit5 and Mockito however I am not too sure at how this would be accomplished. I have the following:

```
@Mock
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Test
public void testRegister() {

    UserDaoImpl userdaoimpl = new UserDaoImpl();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userdaoimpl, "jdbcTemplate", jdbcTemplate);
    Mockito.when(...);
    assertEquals(...);

}
```

What would I have to include in the `Mockito.when()`and `assertEquals()`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: please do **not** concatenate parameters into the SQL string (as you do with your SELECT statement). Always use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? There can be couple of tests here: integration-test: `register()` saves the record into some database, and unit-test: Given a `user`, `jdbcTemplate.update()` is called with specific arguments.

Comment: `register()`, but I am not sure on how to do it